# Syntax error with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
    header.clearfix{:role => "banner"}
      %h1.logo
        %span.company> Cerner
        Care
      %h2.application-name Welcome to the BigData application suite!
      %ul.button-bar
        %li
          %a{:href => "Logout"} Log Out
        %li
          %a{:href => "http://www.google.com", :target => "_blank"} Help
      %span.username 
      -unless current_user.nil?  
      #{current_user.display_name}
    %header.context.clearfix{:role => "banner"}
   %nav.navigation-bar.clearfix{:role => "navigation"}
  %h3.reader-details Account Management Tools
  %a.home{:href => root_path, :role => "link", :title => "Home"}Home
  %em
  %a{:href => "dsonboarding/index", :role => "link"} Data Source Onboarding
  %a{:href => "otherapp/index", :role => "link"} Some Other Application
```

I want to verify if the username is null before displaying the username and haml gives me syntax error for the above code. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: This isn’t a valid Haml excerpt, can you provide an better example? What’s the error that is given? There’s no `username` in the code, but there is `current_user.display_name`; do you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to render the output of the ruby code you need to use '='.

```
-unless current_user.nil?  
  =current_user.display_name
```

Unless the exception occurred on a different line.

I found their [tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html) to be very helpful.